# Is there a way I can reset a Python Arcade window class without restarting the whole project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcade

I have a 2D platformer game in one class I want to re-run so that the level changes when I recall it.

I have tried creating an attribute called `reset(self)` that when called runs the `__init__(self)` subroutine again but that gives the error:

```
*pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 107, in errcheck
    raise GLException(msg)
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid operation'*
```

I've tried so much but can't figure it out.

Anyone got any solutions I might be able to use?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: The stack trace here is also incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not call `__init__` a second time. You can do all the setup in the `reset()` method itself. `__init__` can call `reset()` at least. The other option is using `arcade.View`.